# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm quite new to Java/Eclipse/GAE, but facing with this error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.steve.HelloAppEngine

I just created a Google App Engine Standard Java Project, and added a url mapping for the Servlet (web.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.steve.HelloAppEngine</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the code of a java file.

```
package com.steve;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
    name = "HelloAppEngine",
    urlPatterns = {"/hello"}
)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    response.getWriter().print("Hello App Engine!\r\n");

  }
}
```

[Google App Engine Standard Java Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peaoC.png)

A bit more logs. Please let me know additional info needed.

```
2018-04-22 01:43:06.628:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1262ms
2018-04-22 01:43:06.978:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2018-04-22 01:43:07.287:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=124ms
2018-04-22 01:43:07.822:WARN:oejs.BaseHolder:main: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.steve.HelloAppEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:196)
```

My project structure (not all expanded, though) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohSZN.png)

```
/demo
  /src/main/java
    com.steve
      /com/steve/HelloAppEngine.java
        com.steve.HelloAppEngine
          com.steve.HelloAppEngine.doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
/demo/src/test/java
/demo/build
/demo/src
  /main
    /webapp
      /META-INF
        /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        /WEB-INF
          /lib
            /jstl-1.2.jar
          /appengine-web.xml
          /web.xml
      /favicon.ico
      /index.html
/demo/src/test
```

Comment: can you post the architecture of you project as well?

Comment: Can you see this? Or do you know how I can export the structure (using Eclipse)?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pKV96B9My60X5MoRYfAz3cp0_OLgdr9M

Comment: Added manually. Works?

Comment: It's solved. Apologies. Another small issue affected.

Comment: okay.. that's great.!!

Comment: @Steve, can you write an answer with how you solved this issue so others may see the solution?